# Multiple Where, AND, AS syntax in BigQuery

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have fitness data exported from my smartwatch. It has columns Date, Step_count, and others (which are not required now).

I am trying to organize my activity based on steps as very low, low, moderate, high and very high.

My syntaxes are:

for very low activity:

`select Date, Step_count as very_low_physical_activity from my-second-project-370721.my_activity_2022.my_activity where Step_count<1000`

for low activity:

`select Date, Step_count as low_physical_activity from my-second-project-370721.my_activity_2022.my_activity  where Step_count BETWEEN 1000 and 2500`

and so on for moderate (2500-5000), high (5000-10000) and very high (>10000)

How do I join these queries so that I get all the activity reports in one go?

I tried:

`(select Date, Step_count as very_low_physical_activity from my-second-project-370721.my_activity_2022.my_activity where Step_count<1000)`

`UNION ALL`

`(select Date, Step_count as low_physical_activity from my-second-project-370721.my_activity_2022.my_activity  where Step_count BETWEEN 1000 and 2500)`

`order_by Date`

but am getting results with column as very_low_physical_activity where steps between 0 - 2500 are populated.

Comment: I believe you can find how to join two queries in google-bigquery with small searching in stackoverflow, so the questions seems duplicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASE` is a better approach here instead of the `UNION ALL`

```
select 
    Date, 
    Step_count,
    case 
        when Step_count < 1000 THEN  'very_low_physical_activity'
        when Step_count >= 1000 and Step_count < 2500 THEN 'low_physical_activity'
        when Step_count >= 2500 and Step_count < 5000 THEN 'moderate_physical_activity'
        when Step_count >= 5000 and Step_count < 10000 THEN 'high_physical_activity'
        else 'very_high_physical_activity'
    end as Physical_activity
from my-second-project-370721.my_activity_2022.my_activity
```

Showing in multiple columns:

```
select 
    Date, 
    Step_count,
    case when step_count < 1000 then step_count end as very_low_physical_activity,
    case when step_count >= 1000 and step_count < 2500 then step_count end as low_physical_activity,
    case when Step_count >= 2500 and Step_count < 5000 then step_count end as moderate_physical_activity,
    case when Step_count >= 5000 and Step_count < 10000 then step_count end as high_physical_activity,
    case when step_count >= 1000 then step_count end as very_high_physical_activity
from `my-second-project-370721.my_activity_2022.my_activity`
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. But is it possible to make this query such that physical activities are populated as 4 different columns with their respective steps?

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly. I didn't get it.

Comment: I meant 1000 steps or less as very low physical activity in one column, 1000-2500 steps as low physical activity in another column. The above solution is populating physical activity and its corresponding steps in one column. I want to separate them into 4 different columns.

Comment: Then it will create nulls in other columns. If the step count is 900, i.e. falls under the category step_count < 1000 then under the column very_low_physical_activity shows 900 and other columns will show the value as null. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes. That would be ok.

Comment: I have added the query to the answer. Check it.